# Rails 3.1 - Coffescript doesn't compile to js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I am migrating app from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1. I changed all nessasary config files and installed gems (with help of  [Ryan's screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1)). I have few layouts and i want to load different scripts for them.

I have view:

**layouts/console.html.erb**

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    ...
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "console" %>
    <%= yield :stylesheets%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'console' %>
    ...
    <%= yield :javascripts%>
  </head>
</html>
```

In my assets i created file console.js:

**assets/javascripts/console.js**

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./console
```

Also i created folder **console** with file inside of this folder:

**assets/javascripts/console/users.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  alert "Test"
```

But when i load such page alert doesn't appear.

When i debug page i see that Rails loaded this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/console.js?body=1"></script>
```

Which contains:

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
;
```

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/console/users.js.coffee ?body=1"></script>
```

Which contains:

```
jQuery ->
alert "Test"
;
```

What is my problem? How can i fix this?

**UPD**: links in the head of the page:

```
<head>
   ...
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="PAO2QZ6Z3ykmksXnY55dmCehq+i2COXmSlnZWjErFwA=">
   <link type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/console.css?body=1">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/console/console.css?body=1">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/console/pagination.css?body=1">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/console/search-form.css?body=1">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/console.js?body=1"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/console/users.js.coffee ?body=1"></script>  
</head>
```

Comment: Your problem is that your syntax is all wrong.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Can you provide correct solution? I can't get my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

There is a space in line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/console/users.js.coffee ?body=1"></script>
```

that shouldn't be there!

Make sure there aren't any trailing spaces in the file name of `users.js.coffee`.

**Original answer:** (Wasn't the solution)

It doesn't look like coffeescript has interpreted the line

```
jQuery ->
```

Are you loading jQuery correctly? Make sure you've got

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

in your **Gemfile**, and you've run `bundle install`

It may also be worth trying the alternate syntax of `$ ->`, although it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Yes, i have this gem.
I tried to run `bundle install` again and using `$ ->` and it didn't help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it looks like there is a space in the line
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/console/users.js.coffee ?body=1"></script>`
Do you have a trailing space in the file name?

Comment: You are absolute right! I just noticed it (after changing of the name of the file).

Comment: You can update your answer and i'll set it as correct if you want.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I've updated the answer. Is it SO etiquette to remove the old answer completely or leave it there?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.0 application may missing some code when running on Rails 3.1.

First, check if you have those gems in your Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Second, check if those lines are in config/application.rb:

```
module SAH2Client
 class Application < Rails::Application

    ......

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end

end
```